# How to print List elements with map?

Tags: dart

I would like to print all elements from `List`. I am not sure that `map` suitable for it. Can I do something like:

```dart
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> MyJsonString = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "mike", "code": "01"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "piter", "code": "02"}
  ];
  MyJsonString.map((a) => print(a));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what your want but I guess the following do what your want?

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> MyJsonString = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "mike", "code": "01"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "piter", "code": "02"}
  ];
  MyJsonString.forEach(print);
}
```

Your problem is you are using map method which returns a Iterable. The Iterable is lazy evaluated so the method you are given the map method are only executed when your are using the Iterable (e.g. using toList method on the Iterable to convert it into a list):

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> MyJsonString = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "mike", "code": "01"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "piter", "code": "02"}
  ];
  MyJsonString.map((a) => print(a)).toList();
}
```

But since you just want to run the method on each element you can just use the forEach method instead as showed in the first example.

Comment: Thanks, but if map return lazy in each step why `.toList();` is calling not for every element, but for all result? It's buffering or something like it?

Comment: The toList() method on a Iterable are implemented so it takes all elements from the Iterable and put them into a new List and returns the completed List (lists are not lazy evaluated).The purpose of the map method is to say "run this method for each element and convert it into another type". In you case, you converts each element into Null because the print method does not return anything. But still, the map method are only executed when the returned Iterable are used so we need to make sure it is used (by e.g. use the toList method).

Comment: so `map` will run only after `.toList();` method?

Comment: Well, the map method runs as your expect. But the argument to the map method are a method which are only executed on elements when somebody assess the element through the returned Iterable.